# Trying to align dots along part of a circle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm working on a circle with legs problem and I'm trying to replace n "unseens" legs with dots. But I can't find a good way to align them.

I tried aliging them along an arc, but I can't find a good way to set the center. I found a way somewhere where it supposedly works with parametrizing. But I would basically need to set a center reffering to a point I earlier set relative to another one. If I try it with calc like this

```
plot ($ (c1) + ( {0.7*cos(\x)}, {0.7*sin(\x)} )$ )
```

I get an error. "! Package tikz Error: + or - expected.See the tikz package documentation for explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... }}] plot ($ (c1)"

Here is an image, I'm trying to get the same kind of circles I have on the left on the right:

[image: mystuff]

This is my full code:

```
\documentclass[utf8]{article} %Sets Basic Layout, article has no chapters
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Allows special characters e.g. €, Æ ...
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %For Umlaute, Accents
\usepackage[toc]{appendix} %For Appendices, adds options
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English as default language (for German use ngerman )
\usepackage{newclude} %Some Include Enhancements
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Empty Line between paragraphs instead of spaces.
\usepackage{lmodern} % Sets Font to be lmodern
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fp Float Variables

\usepackage{tikz} %For Drawing with pdflatex
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings} % For Arrow heads in the middle
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text} % For text along path 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} % For relative positioning
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds} % For background layer
\usetikzlibrary{fit} % To make background fit
\usetikzlibrary{calc} % To calculate e.g. the distance between nodes
\usetikzlibrary{shapes} % more shapes   

\tikzset{dot/.style={draw,circle,inner sep=.7pt,fill,node distance=1cm}} %Defining a dot in tikz
\tikzset{dot1/.style={draw,circle,inner sep=.7pt,fill}} % For dots with arbitrary node distance
\tikzset{triangle/.style={draw,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3}} %Triangle
\tikzset{->-/.style={decoration={
  markings,
  mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}}} %Put Arrow head in the middle for ->-
\tikzset{-<-/.style={decoration={ % Same as above but with inverse direction Arrow
  markings,
  mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{<}}},postaction={decorate}}}

\newdimen\XCoord
\newdimen\YCoord

\newcommand*{\ExtCoord}[1]{\path (#1); \pgfgetlastxy{\XCoord}{\YCoord};}%
\newcommand*{\ExtCoordX}[1]{\path (#1); \pgfgetlastxy{\XCoord}{\YCoord} \XCoord}%
\newcommand*{\ExtCoordY}[1]{\path (#1); \pgfgetlastxy{\XCoord}{\YCoord} \YCoord}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newdimen\cix 
\newdimen\ciy
%
\node[draw,circle, minimum size=1cm] (c1) {1L};
%\ExtCoord{c1} ;
%\cix = \XCoord ;
%\ciy = \YCoord ; 
\path [domain=180:360,
postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path, text=. . . . . . ,
text align={fit to path stretching spaces}
}}] plot ({0.7*cos(\x)}, { 0.7*sin(\x)});
%\coordinate (d) at ($ (\cix,\ciy) + (1,3) $)
%edge [thick] node [] {} (c1.40) ;
%
\node [right =.5cm of c1.east] (eq) {$=$} ;
%
\node[right=.5cm of eq.east,draw,circle, minimum size=1cm] (c2) {0L};
\node [above right=.5cm of c2.north east] (l1c2) {$\hat{1}$} 
edge [thick] node [] {} (c2.40) ;
\node [above left=.5cm of c2.north west] (lnc2) {$\hat{n}$} 
edge [thick] node [] {} (c2.140) ;
\node [above left=.5cm of c2.north] (ll1c2) {$l_1$} 
edge [thick] node [] {} (c2.110) ;
\node [above right=.5cm of c2.north] (ll2c2) {$l_2$} 
edge [thick] node [] {} (c2.70) ;
\path [domain=180:360,
postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path, text=. . . . . . ,
text align={fit to path stretching spaces}
}}] plot ({0.7*cos(\x)}, {0.7*sin(\x)}); % the dots
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure of the intended output, but I think a better approach is to use polar coordinates relative to the circular node, instead of text decorations along a plot.

After simplifying your example (removing unused packages and macro definitions), and using the proposed technique, this is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} % For relative positioning

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[draw,circle, minimum size=1cm] (c1) {1L};
\foreach \n in {0,...,5} \fill (c1) +(180+180/5*\n:0.7) circle (1pt);

\node [right =.5cm of c1.east] (eq) {$=$} ;

\node[right=.5cm of eq.east,draw,circle, minimum size=1cm] (c2) {0L};
\node [above right=.5cm of c2.north east] (l1c2) {$\hat{1}$} 
edge [thick] node [] {} (c2.40) ;
\node [above left=.5cm of c2.north west] (lnc2) {$\hat{n}$} 
edge [thick] node [] {} (c2.140) ;
\node [above left=.5cm of c2.north] (ll1c2) {$l_1$} 
edge [thick] node [] {} (c2.110) ;
\node [above right=.5cm of c2.north] (ll2c2) {$l_2$} 
edge [thick] node [] {} (c2.70) ;
\foreach \n in {0,...,5} \fill (c2) +(180+180/5*\n:0.7) circle (1pt);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image: Result]

Also, I think that polar coordinates should be used also for the labelled "legs". This can be combined with a `foreach` loop to simplify the code even further:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[draw,circle, minimum size=1cm] (c1) {1L};
\foreach \n in {0,...,5} \fill (c1) +(180+180/5*\n:0.7) circle (1pt);

\node [right =.5cm of c1.east] (eq) {$=$} ;

\node[right=.5cm of eq.east,draw,circle, minimum size=1cm] (c2) {0L};

\foreach  \angle/\label in {40/$\hat1$,70/$l_2$, 110/$l_1$, 140/$\hat n$} 
  {
     \path (c2) +(\angle:1.2) node (aux) {\label};
     \draw[thick] (c2) -- (aux);
  }

\foreach \n in {0,...,5} \fill (c2) +(180+180/5*\n:0.7) circle (1pt);    
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This is the result now:

[image: Result2]

Comment: Thank you very much for this awnser. It is amazing how simple the code gets with an intelligent approach. As you can tell I am a beginner with TikZ so this helped a lot.

Answer (score 3):

This solution proposes the use of `scope` with labels to place the images in a relative sense where `shift` is used for the right image. Note (c2) circle does not take reference to (c1) or (eq) any more.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}%[utf8]{article} %Sets Basic Layout, article has no chapters
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Allows special characters e.g. €, Æ ...
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %For Umlaute, Accents
\usepackage[toc]{appendix} %For Appendices, adds options
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English as default language (for German use ngerman )
\usepackage{newclude} %Some Include Enhancements
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Empty Line between paragraphs instead of spaces.
\usepackage{lmodern} % Sets Font to be lmodern
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fp Float Variables

\usepackage{tikz} %For Drawing with pdflatex
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings} % For Arrow heads in the middle
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text} % For text along path 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} % For relative positioning
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds} % For background layer
\usetikzlibrary{fit} % To make background fit
\usetikzlibrary{calc} % To calculate e.g. the distance between nodes
\usetikzlibrary{shapes} % more shapes   

\tikzset{dot/.style={draw,circle,inner sep=.7pt,fill,node distance=1cm}} %Defining a dot in tikz
\tikzset{dot1/.style={draw,circle,inner sep=.7pt,fill}} % For dots with arbitrary node distance
\tikzset{triangle/.style={draw,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3}} %Triangle
\tikzset{->-/.style={decoration={
  markings,
  mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}}} %Put Arrow head in the middle for ->-
\tikzset{-<-/.style={decoration={ % Same as above but with inverse direction Arrow
  markings,
  mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{<}}}, postaction={decorate}}}

\newdimen\XCoord
\newdimen\YCoord

\newcommand*{\ExtCoord}[1]{\path (#1); \pgfgetlastxy{\XCoord}{\YCoord};}%
\newcommand*{\ExtCoordX}[1]{\path (#1); \pgfgetlastxy{\XCoord}{\YCoord} \XCoord}%
\newcommand*{\ExtCoordY}[1]{\path (#1); \pgfgetlastxy{\XCoord}{\YCoord} \YCoord}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newdimen\cix 
\newdimen\ciy
%
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=scope1]
\node[draw,circle, minimum size=1cm] (c1) {1L};
%\ExtCoord{c1} ;
%\cix = \XCoord ;
%\ciy = \YCoord ; 
\path [domain=180:360,
postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path, text=. . . . . . ,
text align={fit to path stretching spaces}
}}] plot ({0.7*cos(\x)}, { 0.7*sin(\x)});
%\coordinate (d) at ($ (\cix,\ciy) + (1,3) $)
%edge [thick] node [] {} (c1.40) ;
%
\node [right =.5cm of c1.east] (eq) {$=$} ;
\end{scope}
%
\begin{scope}[shift={($(scope1)+(2cm,3pt)$)}]
\node[draw,circle, minimum size=1cm] (c2) {0L};
\node [above right=.5cm of c2.north east] (l1c2) {$\hat{1}$} 
edge [thick] node [] {} (c2.40) ;
\node [above left=.5cm of c2.north west] (lnc2) {$\hat{n}$} 
edge [thick] node [] {} (c2.140) ;
\node [above left=.5cm of c2.north] (ll1c2) {$l_1$} 
edge [thick] node [] {} (c2.110) ;
\node [above right=.5cm of c2.north] (ll2c2) {$l_2$} 
edge [thick] node [] {} (c2.70) ;
\path [domain=180:360,
postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path, text=. . . . . . ,
text align={fit to path stretching spaces}
}}] plot ({0.7*cos(\x)}, {0.7*sin(\x)}); % the dots
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, the shift approach seems to work nicely too. I didn't know there was this option in TikZ!